# How to implement multi threading for invoking REST URL with multiple data

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have below code base which is gonna hit REST URI and return a response back:

```
   @ApiOperation(responseContainer = "request", response = ETLRequest.class, value = "testValidation")

   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @RequestMapping(value = "/getValue", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
   @ResponseBody
   public Response getETLResponse(@RequestParam("unID") String httpEntity,@RequestParam(value = "PId", defaultValue = "Optional") String pId)throws Exception 
   {
     try {

            if (httpEntity.contains(",")) 
             {

                if (resultSet.size() > 0) 
                {
                    resultSet.clear();
                }

                String[] strArray = httpEntity.split(",");

                for (String str : strArray) 
                {
                    System.out.println(str + "FIRST....");
                    response = RESTInvoker.validateREST(JSONToPOJO
                            .buildURL(str));
                    System.out.println(response + "\t RESPONSE");
                    resultSet.add(response);
                }
                return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED)
                        .entity(resultSet).build();
            } 

         } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();

        }
    }
```

**Sample Request**

```
{
  "unID": "1946249809, 194602775536,194624982809, 19462475536,19462775536,194624002779,19002775536,12494002775536,19462495536,194940536,1949775536,19402775536,1946945536,194475536,194600536,194775536,1946275536,1946205536,1902775536,14002775536,775536",
  "PId": "optional"
}
```

The above code works fine. It will get the UnID as query param, and separate the value by using **(,)** delimiter. And one record of UnID will append into request URI, and will return response as String response above code base.

I just want to achieve the above task in multi threading concept. Like I want to fetch 10 records (10 different threads) from UnID query parm (if it has comma separated values), and invoke the REST URI to speed up the process.

The above code will tak one second to invoke a response. If I have 10 input values in UnId will take 10 seconds to run all. The time will increase based upon test data, and sequence execution.I just want to pick 10 inputs in a second and invoke with REST URI by using different threads.

I'm using Java 7.

Any leads?

Comment: just write your client code inside run method and create multiple threads.

Comment: Can I get any sample piece of code. That would be help me for better understanding.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information like what is your current code and how it is getting executed and what are the input etc.. Also, I'm not sure whether you are asking how to write multi-threading code or it is specific to your scenario. There are millions of examples on how to write simple multi-threading code

Comment: Thanks for your response ravi. It's a piece of code which is get the request query param. If it has , separated value we have to split each value, and append it to REST URI. That's what I did above code. as of now its fetching record one by one from request queryparam. I want to fetch 10 records from request query param, and execute the same action, and post response back. by the way the execution time will reduce.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what are you trying to do and your expectation. But, I bet you better look for example related to ExecutorService and Callable. And, try to write some code and come back to us with your specific problem. Right now, your question is too broad.

Comment: So basically you want this `for (String str : strArray)...` to run in parallel on multiple threads?

Comment: Yes. I want to pick different value from string array and call this RESTInvoker.validateREST(JSONToPOJO.buildURL(str))  line. this line will return response payload. once Its return the thread need to insert into arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java 7 you can do

```
int numberOfTasks = strArray.length;
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++) {
        executor.execute(new MyRunnable(strArray[i], resultSet));
    }
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
executor.shutdown();
```

And you have to create class:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    List<String> resultSet;
    String str;

    public MyRunnable(String str, List<String> resultSet) {
        this.str = str;
        this.resultSet = resultSet;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(str + "FIRST....");
        final String response = RESTInvoker.validateREST(JSONToPOJO .buildURL(str));
        System.out.println(response + "\t RESPONSE");
        resultSet.add(response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 7, you could use use a "ThreadPoolExecutor", essential a pool of threads.  Each thread in the pool runs "simultaneously".  The following code example demonstrates how each thread is run (with a delay).  The static class Task implements runnable, and is executed by the ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BasicThreadPoolExecutorExample {
    static class Task implements Runnable {
        private String name;

        Task(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Long duration = (long) (Math.random() * 10);
                System.out.println("Doing a task during : " + name);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor)  Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            Task task = new Task("Task " + i);
            System.out.println("A new task has been added : " + task.getName());
            executor.execute(task);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Running the code produces the following output:

```
A new task has been added : Task 0
A new task has been added : Task 1
A new task has been added : Task 2
A new task has been added : Task 3
A new task has been added : Task 4
A new task has been added : Task 5
Doing a task during : Task 0
Doing a task during : Task 1
Doing a task during : Task 2
Doing a task during : Task 3
Doing a task during : Task 5
Doing a task during : Task 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may change execution of loop for by a parallel stream:

```
Arrays.stream(strArray).parallel().forEach(str -> {
        System.out.println(str + "FIRST....");
        final String response = RESTInvoker.validateREST(JSONToPOJO
                        .buildURL(str));
        System.out.println(response + "\t RESPONSE");
        resultSet.add(response);
    });
```

Comment: I'm using java 7. Can you please share me sample with JAVA 7.

Comment: I was about to say same. If OP is using Java7 then, it won't work. As stream was introduced in Java8.

Answer (score 0):

Check out

```
private ReadWriteLock iolock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
iolock.readLock().tryLock(); /** and */ iolock.readLock.unlock();

iolock.writeLock.tryLock(); /** and */ iolock.writeLock().unlock();
```